# Minimal DFA with language

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I have a doubt about this task, have I done it correctly?

The task is: Construct a minimal DFA that accepts the following language:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is by the definition of language. 
x can be a or b.
w - includes all words formed from a and b, including the empty word (but we ignore that in DFA). It needs to accept all words of the form xwx.

Comment: I think TonyK is saying that your automaton will accept any string of length at least $2$, but this is not what the language specifies. For example, it will accept $ab$, even though $ab$ does not take the form $xwx$. Also, on the topic of minimality, you could merge the states $g_1$ and $g_2$, as well as $g_3$ and $g_4$.

Comment: @TheoBendit How do you think I can merge q1 and q2 for example, when from q0 different symbols lead to different states in DFA, wouldn't that be possible only in NFA?

Comment: Why is my question useless? Why -1?

Comment: You could have $q_0$ connect to a new merged state $Q_1$ by both $a$ and $b$. This state can connect, by both $a$ and $b$, to a new merged state $Q_2$, which is accepting, and connects to itself by $a$ and $b$. This is a three state DFA that accepts the same language as the one you drew.

Comment: @TheoBendit So with q0 I can go with 'a' and 'b' to q1, from which I can also go with 'a' and with 'b' to q2, from which I can also go with 'a' and with 'b' to q3 which is the final state, also if 'a' or 'b' appears in q3 it goes to q3 again. Did I reason correctly?

Comment: Only three states are necessary. The final state is $q_2$, which is accepting, and points to itself with $a$ and $b$. Look, I wouldn't worry too much: the DFA is not correct. I was just trying to point out that even if the DFA did produce the language, it can be reduced by merging a couple of pairs of states.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Your initial comment has it backwards. The specification $\{xwx\,|\,x\in\{a,b\}\land w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$ is simply the set of all strings of length $2$ or more. So the DFA can be much simpler.

Comment: @TonyK No, that would be $\{xwy : x, y \in \{a, b\} \land w \in \{a, b\}^*\}$. The set written is the set of all strings of length $2$ or more that begin and end with the same letter.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Yes, I deleted my comments, which were based on a misreading of the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @logicnotfound I find your question very useful, but unfortunately, there are some serial downvoters on this site.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin No, my comment wasn't wrong, it was just highly confusing. I was saying that the DFA that was presented by the OP, which was for the wrong language, could have been simplified down to three states. I agree that five are required for a DFA for the correct language.

Comment: @TheoBendit OK, I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $A = \{a, b\}$, your language is $aA^*a \cup bA^*b$. Its minimal automaton has five states:

$\hskip 40pt$[image]